# How do I make javadoc style commets for android ndk c++ in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse

I am developing an application for android using the ndk.

I want to make comments and description for the classes and function I write such that they show up in intelli-sense like they do for java (android-SDK).

while writing java code it is very easy to do so by just making a block comment before the class or function declaration (/** then press enter key shortcut)

however If I try to do so in c++ two things happen:

1. When hovering over a function name the the block comment and whole function code is displayed in the popup

2.When the function list shows up using the dot (.) operator then no details show up when you highlight a function

What is the proper way to use javadoc style for c++ in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

For C++ you should use Doxygen. There is a Doxygen plugin for Eclipse which is called [eclox](http://home.gna.org/eclox/).

Comment: The website says **Since December the 1st of 2009, the development and the maintenance of eclox are discontinued !**

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that you will find anything better. It may be discontinued, but it does its job pretty well.